# Is there any solution to my eloquent ? It takes too long

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the first and the latest data from this [fingerprint table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85lKL.jpg), but it take too long because the table got over 100k records. Is there any solution to this? Thanks before

Here is my code :

```
$checkInOut = Fingerprint::where('USERID', 317)->where('CHECKTIME', '>=', $startDate)->where('CHECKTIME', '<=', $dayAfterStartDate)->get();
$checkIn = $checkInOut->first();
$checkOut = $checkInOut->last();`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covering index on `USERID` and `CHECKTIME` columns will speed up data retrieval.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_fingerprint ON Fingerprint(userid, checktime);
```